# "Normal" time for query execution

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table in a MariaDB database with ~700,000,000 rows. I have indexed some columns of it.

My question is whether my DB behaves "normaly" or not - because I have not had previous experience with such an amount of data.

Take a look at these queries and please let me know if you think this is normal response time:

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT(QualityLevel) ) FROM patient_records;
+---------------------------------+
| count( DISTINCT(QualityLevel) ) |
+---------------------------------+
|                          265595 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (1.248 sec)
```

This I think is great response time. However, look below:

```
select count(QualityLevel) from patient_records where QualityLevel>10.14;
+---------------------+
| count(QualityLevel) |
+---------------------+
|           700756562 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (3 min 10.324 sec)
```

Not so great (I assume?). And, more:

```
select count(recordID) from patient_records where QualityLevel>10.14 and snpID='.';
+-----------------+
| count(recordID) |
+-----------------+
|        56627747 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (23 min 53.028 sec)
```

Quite slow this one, although both columns (`QualityLevel` and `snpID`) are indexed.

I will need to build a web interface for these queries, but it can't happen that it takes 25 minutes to execute. What am I missing here? Maybe DB partiotining would help (don't know anything about it, so any suggestion would be highly appreciated).

My `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/home/ssd/mysql_datadir
tmpdir=/home/ssd/mysql_tmdir
socket=/home/ssd/mysql_datadir/mysql.sock
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4GB
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size = 10M
query_cache_limit=256k

[client]
port=3306
socket=/home/ssd/mysql_datadir/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

My SHOW CREATE TABLE is:

```
patient_records | CREATE TABLE `patient_records` (
  `recordID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MRD_sample_FORMAT_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DataType` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `SequencingOrigin` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `ChrNo` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `ChrPos` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `snpID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `NuclREF` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `NuclALT` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
  `QualityLevel` float NOT NULL,
  `FilterString` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `InfoString` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `GT` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DP` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GQ` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PL` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recordID`),
  KEY `fk_patients_idx` (`MRD_sample_FORMAT_id`),
  KEY `ChrNo` (`ChrNo`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `snpID` (`snpID`),
  KEY `idx_patient_records_ChrNo` (`ChrNo`),
  KEY `position_chrom` (`ChrPos`),
  KEY `quality` (`QualityLevel`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=700756618 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: You have 2 indexes on `ChrNo`; you could drop one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to have `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, but I will make some guesses...

You have `INDEX(QualityLevel)`, and that index is smaller than the buffer_pool?
You have been doing a bunch of queries; these were not the first?  (Hence some things are cached.)
You did not use `SQL_NO_CACHE` to avoid the Query cache?

How much RAM do you have?  `innodb_buffer_pool_size=4GB` is rather small unless you have only 6GB.

The `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` seems too fast -- probably caching helped.

When doing timing tests:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...   -- to avoid the Query cache.
```

and run the query twice -- to compensate for I/O caching.

**Responding to comments**

You should switch to InnoDB.  Then, with 250GB of RAM, set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200G`.  This will help InnoDB performance.  (Note: MyISAM does not use that at all; instead, it uses `key_buffer_size`, which should be set to about 50G for a MyISAM-only setup.)

In general, adding a useful index is worth doing -- in spite of the negative cost considerations (disk space an insert cost).

When building a composite (multi-column) index, the cardinality of the individual columns is irrelevant.  The index becomes a unit, the components of which are not noticed.

For this query:

```
select count(recordID) from patient_records
      where QualityLevel>10.14 and snpID='.';
```

the following is optimal *in this order*:

```
INDEX(snpID, ,      -- because of `=`
      QualityLevel, -- a range, so comes after `=`
      recordID)     -- tacked on to make it "covering"
```

A note about `COUNT(recordID)` -- that checks which rows have a non-NULL value for `recordID`.  This test is unnecessary since it is declared `NOT NULL`.  I suggest getting in the habit of simply saying `COUNT(*)`.

With `COUNT(*)`, `INDEX(snpID, QualityLevel)` would be as good.

To design the optimal indexes, you need to know the `SELECTs`, `DELETEs`, and `UPDATEs`.  You cannot pre-guess.  See my [*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

Another note:  The order of `WHERE` clauses does *not* matter; the Optimizer tries all reorderings of the `AND` clauses.  It will try all reorderings of multiple tables `JOINed` together.  (`LEFT` may or may not limit what the Optimizer will try.)

**need to build a web interface for these queries**

It is passe to say "Exactly 56627747 widgets" in a web interface.  Even "About 56 million" is rarely used these days.  And that could be efficiently achieved by a nightly job that recomputes that, and other, statistics about your data.

If you do need both precision and speed, then build a Summary Table and query it.  That table could, for example, have daily counts for the number of widgets in various quality brackets.

[*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) are the key to billion-row datasets.

Comment: Hi Rick! Many thanks for your time! How much RAM should I put for inno_buffer? The computer that the DB is running has ~250 GB of RAM. Also, does this buffer help MYISAM table queries as well? And, last question: do I need, as you suggest, have a composite INDEX when I am using 2 columns?

Comment: Afaik, innodb_buffer_pool_size is a setting for InnoDB tables only. For MyISAM you should set "key_buffer_size" variable in your config file.
About index question, It always depends. Indexes are not cost-free, it should compensate its cost with the performance gain. You should take storage and DML operation costs(every index needs its own space and to be updated separately) into consideration when you create index. Also choose the column order wisely, always put selective column first.

Comment: Hi Bahtiyar, thank you! So, what you are telling me is that one needs to kind of "pre-guess" what the selects will be and define indexes (either single or composite) according to this?

Comment: In most cases you either detect a poor select query or you are the one who develops the query. Thus, you don't have to "pre-guess". I was actually trying to point out that you have to ask these questions and determine whether you need an index based on the results. How often this query will run? If I index these columns what is the new execution time? Does it worth it? If yes, then which column is more selective and distinct? If you have a chance to touch application layer and change select queries, adjust them according to your new index. Use your selective column first in the where clause.

Comment: @bioplanet - I responded to these Comments by adding to my Answer.  Note that I replaced my previous composite index since I discovered a mistake.

Comment: @BahtiyarSametÇoban - You state a couple of common misconceptions about indexes.  I address them in my update to my Answer.

Comment: @RickJames So, innoDB is preferred choice over MyISAM in my case? And you think that I can be having such queries in a acceptable time? What *is* acceptable I wonder? Can you imagine more or less? I understand that 20 mins is really slow, but is it? And what is your opinion about DB partitioning? Is it worth investing in it or is it not related to my issue? Lastly, I have heard somewhere about storing indexes separately. Is this a thing, and how does it help? Many many thanks for your time, your input is highly appreciated!

Comment: InnoDB is preferred in virtually all cases (today).  Any advice to the contrary is probably years old.  Many benchmarks show that InnoDB is as fast or faster than MyISAM.  (Of course, many of the benchmarks come from Oracle, which will be removing MyISAM in some future version.)

Comment: @bioplanet  - and, yes, 23 minutes is "slow".  But that is a lot of data to work with, and you don't have the optimal index, and you are using MyISAM, etc.

Comment: @bioplanet - "Partitioning is not a performance panacea".  I don't (yet) see any benefit for PARTITIONing for you.  Only a [_few use cases_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) benefit.

Comment: @bioplanet - Storing indexes separately usually has zero benefit.  I suggest it is not worth the effort.

Comment: @bioplanet - and (added to my Answer), I commented on your need for the 23-minute query.

Comment: @RickJames thanks a ton! I will look into your suggestions!

Comment: @RickJames Ok, I am coming back to this, since I tried the InnoDB approach. I copied everything, and also the keys are enabled. I also gave the innodb_buffer 90/125 GB of my machine's RAM. BUT, it really does not seem to work at all. Not faster than MyISAM, but, really, it hangs. And I am talking about the same COUNT test command... What did I do wrong?

Comment: `select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from patient_records;
+-----------+
| count(*)  |
+-----------+
| 700756617 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (12 min 21.177 sec)`